# Amazon Cloudwatch Agent won't start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

After installing Cloudwatch Agent on Amazon Linux 2 EC2, I ran `cloudwatch-agent-ctl status`

This command shows the status as `stopped`

I tried running 'cloudwatch-agent-ctl status` and got the following message:

`cwagent-otel-collector will not be started "as it has not been configured yet"`

Am not sure if the above message is causing CWAgent to not start. Any pointers?

Any pointers on how to find why my CWAgent won't start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you can start your CW agent, you must configure it. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-cloudwatch-agent-configuration-file.html):

> Before running the CloudWatch agent on any servers, you **must create a CloudWatch agent configuration file**.

You can follow the docs how to setup the config files, before running the agent.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. My config file was empty n one of the instances where the agent wouldn't start! Thanks much!

Comment: I'm getting the error above even though I have created an agent configuration file.

Comment: I created a config file, but it was invalid (had a missing } character). This caused it to silently fail to start. The start process copies the file to /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/ but the copy in there was blank, and this was the problem. Look in /var/log/amazon/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log to investigate